# Helm nginx-ingress 404 error on all routes on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to deploy an app to GKE. I am using [nginx-ingress](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress) controller and I have a bunch of `ingress` rules for every route. For some reason which am not sure, I am getting a 404 error on all the routes/pages.

One of the `ingress` resource definitions is:-

```
{{- $fullName := include "nginx.fullname" . -}}
{{- $ingressPath := .Values.ingress.path -}}
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}-base
  labels:
    app: oxtrust
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: "/identity"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: "sha1"

spec:
{{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
      {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . | quote }}
      {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ . | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: {{ $ingressPath }}
            backend:
              serviceName: oxtrust
              servicePort: 8080
  {{- end }}
```

On minikube the setup is working okay since I do need to use `nginx-ingress`.

I really don't understand what I am doing wrong. I read somewhere about mandatory and cloud-generic objects should be deployed but I am not sure about that.

Someone shed some light on this please. Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide informations from `kubectl describe ing <name_of_ingress>`. Could you try to add `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` and try if it works then? Could you try to delete app-root and try with rewrite-target and try if it works?